# Mesh crinkles when moving armature!

Tags: armature

[image]Why does my mesh crinkle when I move the armature and how can I fix this?? Please help! I want my mesh's arm to move normally like a real arm[image]

[enter image description here][3]

Comment: the arm also for some reason affects the side of the stomach. I just want the arm to rotate and look normal with no crinkles and not affect any other parts of the mesh

Comment: Did you make this figure with dynatopo? It looks like it from you images. You will need to retopo before rigging.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your mesh in *Edit Mode*? I guess your topology is bad (probably you have a bad edge flows and n-gons there).